# WPF - Reusability of DataTemplate code out of items collection

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, mvvm

I am using Bing maps in my WPF project, and I want to use common style overall project View with map. It is not important that it's about Bing maps, problem here is in reusability of code defined in DataTemplate also for single object of ViewModel.

In the folowing code, there is DataTemplate for images placed on map. It has some properties bind on ViewModel item from collection.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeadingArrowsDataTemplate">
    <Image Source="/Intens.C2XTestPlatform.Frontend;component/Images/Maps/Arrow.png"
           m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding PointLocation}"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1"
           Width="100"
           Height="100"
           Visibility="{Binding Path=PointLocation, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Heading}" />
                <TranslateTransform X="-50"
                                    Y="-100" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use it in the first View for ViewModels collection (`RelevanceLinesVM`):

```
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="{Binding MapCredentialsProvider}"
           Mode="Road"
           x:Name="ucMap">
        <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelevanceLinesVM}"
                           helpers:MapFixBehavior.FixUpdate="True"
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HeadingArrowsDataTemplate}"
    </m:Map>
```

In other View, I have only single ViewModel object (`RelevanceLineVM`), and I have to copy-paste code from DataTemplate for the same appearance and binding.

```
   <m:Map Name="ucMap"
           Mode="Road"
           CredentialsProvider="{Binding MapCredentialsProvider}">
        <Image DataContext="{Binding RelevanceLineVM}"
               Source="/Intens.C2XTestPlatform.Frontend;component/Images/Maps/Arrow.png"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1"
               Width="100"
               Height="100"
               m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding PointLocation}"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=PointLocation, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Heading}" />
                    <TranslateTransform X="-50"
                                        Y="-100" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </m:Map>
```

How can I create common template for usage for both single ViewModel and collection of ViewModels?

**Edit**

ASh's answer works, but unfortunately only for these properties in DataTemplate, which are inherited from `ContentControl` class. Other are not bound properly.

Answer (score 1):

add ContentControl and reuse `HeadingArrowsDataTemplate` for its ContentTemplate

```
<m:Map Name="ucMap"
       Mode="Road"
       CredentialsProvider="{Binding MapCredentialsProvider}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelevanceLineVM}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource HeadingArrowsDataTemplate}"/>
</m:Map>
```

Comment: It works percetly, except of `m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding PointLocation}"`.

Comment: @Majak, unfortunately I'm not familiar with Map, MapItemsControl or MapLayer.Position and how they work together, but I would try to repeat `m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding PointLocation}"` on ContentControl as well

Comment: OK this helped. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that it works only for these properties in DataTemplate, which are inherited from `FrameworkElement` class. Other are not bound properly.